# jQuery evaluate last word only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

How would I make jJvascript/jQuery evaluate the last word entered?

Example (doe ra fa la si do) Only evaluate do

Very similar to Google's search box. I want only to evaluate after a space and have that word searched for with an Ajax call.

Here's the code I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ajaxcall();
    var x = setInterval(ajaxcall, 1000);

    function ajaxcall() {
        var nameid = $('#word').val();
        if (nameid.match(/^\s*$/)) {
            // nothing, or nothing but whitespace
        } else {
            $.get('mysqlquery.php?id=' + nameid, function(data) {
                $('#loadbox').append(data + ' ');
            });
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: i think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571686/fastest-way-performance-wise-to-get-last-word-in-a-space-separated-string) will help you

Comment: Thank you for the fast response but I need javascript/jquery The string can become very very long

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    ajaxcall();
    var x = setInterval(ajaxcall,1000);

function ajaxcall(){
    var nameid = $('#word').val().split(' ');
    nameid = nameid[nameid.length-1];
        if (nameid.match(/^\s*$/)) {
        // nothing, or nothing but whitespace
    } else {
        $.get('mysqlquery.php?id='+nameid, function(data){
        $('#loadbox').append(data+' ');     
              });
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: Split the string with `.split(' ')` method, this returns an array of strings, last member of this array is all what you need.

Comment: What about using the .pop() method? Doesn't that get you the last element of the array?

Comment: Yes, `nameid=nameid.pop();` will do too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.split()` to convert the string into an array and then using `.pop()` to return the last element in the array:

```
function lastWord(subject)
{
    var ar = subject.split(" ");
    return ar.pop();
}

lastWord("some amazing sentence"); // sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return the last word of the string:

```
var str = 'doe ra fa la si do',
    patt = /[^\s]*$/;
alert(str.match(patt)); // Returns `do`
```